# Authentication and Data Posting Issues in Next.js 13 Chat Application with next-auth and Prisma Client

Tags: prisma, next.js13, next-auth, next-api

I am currently developing a chat application using Next.js 13 with next-auth and Prisma Client. the code is in this[repository](https://github.com/Sachinv220/chat).

#### Authentication in API Endpoints

I have encountered an issue with authenticating users in my API endpoints using `getServerSession(authOptions)`(always returns null in api endpoints). This problem is similar to the one discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7423), where the proposed solution was to call the authentication function directly.

#### Data Posting

there are only two options to post data which is using server actions or posting the data directly from the client component. However, I am hesitant to use server actions as they may not be stable yet. Can I safely use `PrismaClient()` in the client component, or does it pose a risk of leaking sensitive information?

is there any solution?